# A specific media query not working

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, less, media-queries

I have styled the `@screen-xs-max` and `@screen-sm-max`. Both of those queries worked. Now I am trying to style `@screen-md-max` and the styles wont apply to a certain div. Not all styles - just to a particular div. They dont even show up at all when you inspect the element?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="screenshot-projects bottom-border wrap" style="background-color:#fff;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="projects-img">
                    <img src="~/Images/img-lgipad.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

**Less:**

```
@media (max-width:@screen-md-max) {

    .screenshot-projects {

        projects-img {
            max-width: 300px!important;
        }
    }
}
```

The only style not applying is the one to the image size - it's instead taking up the entire screen, and this only happens once i resize to medium. At xs and s it's  `max:100%;` and it applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the dot

```
@media (max-width:@screen-md-max) {

    .screenshot-projects {

        .projects-img {
            max-width: 300px!important;
        }
    }
}
```